# add buttons programmatically to a template using Angular and typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

I'm trying to add a component (button) to an angular template, but it doesn't work as expected:

basicButton.component.html

```
<button type="button" (click)="changeName()">{{label}}</button>
```

**basicButton.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "basic-button",
  templateUrl: "./basicButton.component.html"
})
export class BasicButtonComponent {
  label: string = "default";

  public changeLabel(l: string) {
    this.label = l;
  }
}
```

**form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { BasicButtonComponent } from "./basicButton.component";

@Component({
  selector: "form-component",
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
<basic-button></basic-button>
{{button2}}`
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Mario";
  button2: BasicButtonComponent;

  setButtonText(t: string) {
    this.button2.changeLabel(t);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.button2 = new BasicButtonComponent();
    this.setButtonText("test1");
  }
}
```

the problem: the first button is rendered correctly, while the second button {{button2}} shows up as  [object Object]. How can i actually tell Angular to inject this object into the template?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `FormComponent` > `template` get the value of the `button2` object:

```
{{button2.label}}
```

**Update.**

The double curly-braces( **{{}}** ) are used for [interpolation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#interpolation), and not for [Components](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#components) nestings.

To communicate across `Components`, use [Services](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#services). (You won't need to use `new` to create instances of Components, check this: https://plnkr.co/edit/GQq3mIx9rpyI1DkDKtSk?p=preview)

---

Check this example: https://plnkr.co/edit/wq7LyKuYGtKtCGIgE8G3?p=preview and try to explain better what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: in this way the label shows up, but i need to show the button, not just the label. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call function in a child component, which `BasicButtonComponent` is, better use **[`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html)**.

**Form Component**, first import:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

then in component:

```
@ViewChild(BasicButtonComponent) basicButtonComp: BasicButtonComponent;

setButtonText(t: string){
   this.basicButtonComp.changeLabel(t);
}
```

That should work just fine! :)